# How to handle NSURLRequest HTTP error 303?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, http, nsurlrequest

When I run my NSURLRequest in Cocoa, I get a 303 HTTP error, which is a redirect. How can I pull the proper URL to redirect to? Is it in the error variable, or somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check out the automatic handling of redirects with NSURLConnection:

[Handling Redirects and other Request Changes](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/RequestChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009506-SW1)

If you'd like to handle it manually, the redirect url is in the response's 'Location' header. Here's how you can grab it in your `connection:didReceiveResponse` delegate method.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
    // ... if the response status is 303 ...
    if ([response respondsToSelector:@selector(allHeaderFields)]) {
        NSString* location = [[httpResponse allHeaderFields] valueForKey:@"Location"];
            // do whatever with the redirect url 
    }
}
```

Comment: Sometimes we get relative url in location headers. Can you please suggest how to handle those? e.g I am opening a page m.espn.go.com and in response Location header field I get Location: /index. How to handle this.